# Python: Declare 2 Byte Variables

Tags: python, memory, numbers, int, sizeof

Is there a python module that allows me to store a number in a significantly smaller object than `int`?

My memory is not big enough for some of my data structures, so I would like to represent numbers using as little space as possible.

The problem is **I store the values in a tree-structure**:

All integers are either keys or values. Maybe then the actual size won't be reduced much when using smaller variables - I don't know.

Comment: in Python data is not typed.

Comment: If you use `numpy` arrays, you can type them, e.g. `np.array([100, 200, 300], dtype=np.uint8)` - see [`numpy.dtype`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html).

Comment: @Begueradj Python data is of course typed.  Values have types, but names do not.

Answer (score 3):

as much I understand your last comment regarding numpy, you use a treelike structure.

You always can use an integer array also to store a tree.

For example:

```
index 0 = root     1                     5
      0   1   2    3   4   5 ....        15
   +-------------------------------------------------------+
   | 10 | 5 | 1 ||      ......                             |
   +-------------------------------------------------------+
          |   |    ^                     ^
          |   +----+                     |
          +------------------------------+
```

In this example, every entry is stored in three entries of the array and the first entry is the value and the others are the (relative -- multiply by 3) indices of the children.

So you can store any treelike data structure in an `array`.

There is only the problem, that using the references is a little more complicated to program.

Also when your "pointers" have a different size (for example you need >65k entries -- you will need 32bit integers) you must use the bigger sizes. Of course you also could store the three values in two or even three arrays. Just make 3 arrays, one for the value (eg. only 16bit) and two for the references. In this case, you don't need to do any multiplication by yourself since your index will be the same as the normal array index in these arrays.

And by the way: I also guess, that your win would be low, when you would implement it with `numpy` and let every entry in your tree be an array itself or use small objects containing just one value, since Python has a significant overhead for any object that is stored in the system. But when you use a small amount of arrays like in the example, every array is an object and the overhead is neglect-able since you store many of your entries in a small amount of arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `numpy` arrays:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array([0, 1, 2, 127, -128], dtype='int8')
array([   0,    1,    2,  127, -128], dtype=int8)
```

`np.int8` for example will give you efficient storage for signed integers up to `2**7 - 1`.

Warning: values out of range will "wrap around" *without* any overflow errors:

```
>>> np.int8(128)
-128
```

Of course, there are other `dtype`-s and which is appropriate for you depends on the range of values you need.

Comment: The problem is I store the values in a tree-structure: All integers are either keys or values. Maybe then the actual size won't be reduced much when using smaller variables - I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

### Memory-compact design

Your task is clearly directed towards a memory light-weight footprint of some `2B`-values.

The solution in Python has a few more things to take into account.

Assuming the range of values, meeting the range-of-values represented within a `2B`-scope of `int`-s ( a range of numbers `0..65535` ) to be memory-efficient is just an illusion.

Your design shall take into account, as a minimum, the **overheads** of associated with an object's "internal_**representation**"  + the overheads associated with object-instance's **access-methods**, to get a number "there" and "back" ( not speaking about performance impact, as your requirement was focused on low-memory-footprint, but the smarter are the proxy-data-structures, the bigger typically grow the data-structure access/maintenance CPU-costs ).

If your main motivation was to design for a low-memory foot-print, the worst-case scenario shall sum up all these static memory-allocations + the requirements for any dynamic-allocations, requested during the access-methods' and object-modifications' operations + the size of the `import`-ed module(s) sizes.

Once speaking about `numpy` -- a great tool -- you would get a great & powerful library for fast, vectorised array manipulations, with a given cell-data representation ( `dtype = numpy.uint8` ).

The hidden-part ( for any assumption on the code-design low-memory-footprint ) is to **take into account the overall memory-cost of the approach.**

Compare not just an object size but also the Class-related overhead ( immense list of numpy methods not shown for clarity ):

```
>>> anIntOBJECT= 8
>>> anIntOBJECT.__sizeof__()   # ____________________________instance-method works
12
>>> sys.getsizeof(anIntOBJECT) # kindly do not modify the MCVE with erroneous code
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined
>>> dir(anIntOBJECT)
['__abs__', '__add__', '__and__', '__class__', '__cmp__', '__coerce__', '__delattr__', '__div__', '__divmod__', '__doc__', '__float__', '__floordiv__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__getnewargs__', '__hash__', '__hex__', '__index__', '__init__', '__int__', '__invert__', '__long__', '__lshift__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__neg__', '__new__', '__nonzero__', '__oct__', '__or__', '__pos__', '__pow__', '__radd__', '__rand__', '__rdiv__', '__rdivmod__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rfloordiv__', '__rlshift__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__ror__', '__rpow__', '__rrshift__', '__rshift__', '__rsub__', '__rtruediv__', '__rxor__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__sub__', '__subclasshook__', '__truediv__', '__trunc__', '__xor__', 'bit_length', 'conjugate', 'denominator', 'imag', 'numerator', 'real']
>>> len( dir( anIntOBJECT ) )                  # Class-methods
64
```

Another approach with a string-based data-representation:

```
>>> aStrOBJECT = "08"
>>> aStrOBJECT.__sizeof__()    # ____________________________instance-method works
23
>>> sys.getsizeof(aStrOBJECT)  # kindly do not modify the MCVE with erroneous code
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined
>>> dir( aStrOBJECT )
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getnewargs__', '__getslice__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '_formatter_field_name_split', '_formatter_parser', 'capitalize', 'center', 'count', 'decode', 'encode', 'endswith', 'expandtabs', 'find', 'format', 'index', 'isalnum', 'isalpha', 'isdigit', 'islower', 'isspace', 'istitle', 'isupper', 'join', 'ljust', 'lower', 'lstrip', 'partition', 'replace', 'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition', 'rsplit', 'rstrip', 'split', 'splitlines', 'startswith', 'strip', 'swapcase', 'title', 'translate', 'upper', 'zfill']
>>> len( dir( aStrOBJECT ) )
71
```

One more primary archetype for a mutable-sequence:

```
>>> aBytearrayOfINTs = bytearray()                                # in python base
>>> aBytearrayOfINTs.__sizeof__() # _________________________instance-method works
24
>>> dir( aBytearrayOfINTs )
['__add__', '__alloc__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__iadd__', '__imul__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'append', 'capitalize', 'center', 'count', 'decode', 'endswith', 'expandtabs', 'extend', 'find', 'fromhex', 'index', 'insert', 'isalnum', 'isalpha', 'isdigit', 'islower', 'isspace', 'istitle', 'isupper', 'join', 'ljust', 'lower', 'lstrip', 'partition', 'pop', 'remove', 'replace', 'reverse', 'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition', 'rsplit', 'rstrip', 'split', 'splitlines', 'startswith', 'strip', 'swapcase', 'title', 'translate', 'upper', 'zfill']
>>> len( dir( aBytearrayOfINTs ) )
76
```

### Real data-structure implementation: access & maintenance methods decide

In all cases, the data-structure access/maintenance methods will be a deciding factor, maybe more, than just the single-value ( minimum representation ) memory-footprint expectation.

Comment: I don't know, which architecture is targeted by the original author, but in most cases, the class based costs are neglectable against the instance costs. In most cases you have really many more instances than the cost for the class. Only when you really operate on meager hardware (like some embedded systems with <1MB of memory) you will care about the costs that importing a module or using some classes. It also must be said, that you have the class related overhead in Python as soon as you do the import of the module -- all classes contained will be added into memory at once.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately a numpy uint8 still takes 12 bytes, so I guess the only way out would be to use cython...

Comment: How many 2B-s you need to store? How fast do you need to .put() / .get() [usec] per call?

Comment: @RadioControlled, have you looked at my answer to your question. Yes, a numpy uint8 still takes 12 bytes, since the normal object overhead is added. But when you use an array, the single entries will only use as much as needed by the type (1 byte for uint8).

Comment: @user3666197: you shouldn't call methods like `__sizeof__` directly.  Importing sys and using sys.getsizeof is the right way to get the size of an object.

Comment: Salutes to Boston & thanks for the expressed advice. Could you kindly be more exact on any rationale behind? Why not calling an instance method ( once optimising the code for having a low-memory-footprint end-to-end ) at a cost of adding another module to be imported to then call there residing method? Thank you, Ned.

Comment: Dunder names are meant for Python to invoke.  For example, you use `len(x)`, not `x.__len__()`.  Importing a module is not a burden.

Comment: The tree is realized through dictionaries, so it is either impossible or too complex for me to use the array-tree-structure. Each non-leaf node is a pair [dict, int] and dict is a mapping int -> node. Leafs are plain ints to save memory.

Answer (score 1):

The `numpy` answer is a good one.  Another simpler alternative is to use the `array` module in the stdlib.

```
>>> import array
>>> array_of_ints = array.array("I")
>>> sys.getsizeof(array_of_ints)
28L
```